# Clean up REST response in client or on server?

Tags: php, json, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I am creating an app in `C#` calling a `RESTful` service coded in `php` returning `Json` data.

All is working quite well - except that some results I get from my server might contain additional server-side info.

To convey additional information on what happens on server side, I use `echo` calls, which are then added in front of the "return" of my `RESTFul` function.

`PHP` side looks as follows:

```
echo "testing credentials...\r\n";
// returns user in DB table if success, null otherwise...!
$user = User::doLogin($username, $password, $apiCaller);
if ($user == null) {
    echo "login failed...\r\n";
    return null;
}
echo "login success...\r\n";
```

When password is wrong, we get following output

```
testing credentials...
user is... user1
checking pwd......
NULL
login failed...
```

and when the method succeeds, we get the following response

```
testing credentials...
user is... user1
checking pwd......
login success...
NULL
```

When I then get the result back on `C#` side using following code:

```
 // get message on some url with a previously create HttpClient
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
 var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
 var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 if (res != null) {
     // this will actually throw an error as the deserialization fails due
     // due to the non-Json parts...
     var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(res);
 }
```

I get an `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 1, position 1.` with a content as follows

```
  RESTFul server call to function Login for user...
  User found, checking password
  Grant access with status:
  <<----here comes the actual JSON data.... ---------->>
```

Not too surprising, in fact - the question is what is the suggested approach ?

**A.** Redirect `echo` output to something else on the server side (where and how to make sure I retrieve the information on client side) ?

**B.** Clean-up the answer before deserializing it?

Comment: If your server claims to be returning JSON, then it must return valid JSON and only valid JSON. Either embed the additional info as part of your JSON return value, or if you're just using it for internal debugging, write it to a log file instead of returning it with the API response.

Comment: @deceze you are right, thanks. So can I redirect the echo to a temp variable, then "jsonify" it at some point?

Answer (score 0):

IMO clean up the response on the server before returning it to the client. As @deceze pointed out; if the server claims the content body is json, it should be only json. On a side note, is the server responding with a Content-Type header?

Comment: Yea, then the server should only be responding with valid json in the response body.

Comment: Well turns out parts of my code write to output wihtout knowing which part and I'm quite unable to debug it.
Anyway, what I did is redirect echo to variable and it works. But still, it's a bit a dirty approach...
As for IMO cleanup - can you provide an example

Comment: Could you provide the PHP part of your application, I'd be willing to help out with it; c# though I do not know.

Comment: I updated the question with the PHP code... It seems some process is writing to the method content, but I am unable to isolate which part as, as you can see, the NULL prints out at different places depending on the method's answer... Really, NO CLUE what is going on!